# CancellationTokenSource does not cancel task after given timeout

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am learning TAP and I like to explore TPL dataflow using unit tests. I have the following one that I am unable to understand:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(500);
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(cts.Token);
var agent = new ActionBlock<FakeMessage>( async evt =>
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    tcs.SetResult(true);
});

agent.Post(new FakeMessage());
try
{
    var result = await tcs.Task;
    Assert.Fail();
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

I was expecting it to raise the timeout defined on the first line and to catch the `OperationCanceledException`, but I always end up with the `Assert.Fail` following `await tcs.Task`. Could someone explain me what is not going well with my assumptions?

Comment: Where are you cancelling the token?

Comment: @Lee: There's a timeout passed to the `CancellationTokenSource` constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet - So there is, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TaskCompletionSource` doesn't accept a `CancellationToken`.

It does accept an `Object` state and you can technically pass a `CancellationToken` into it, but it wouldn't do anything, especially not cancel the `TaskCompletionSource`.

If you want to cancel the `TaskCompletionSource` you can do that with a simple timeout:

```
Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(t => tcs.SetCancelled());
```

You can also create a `TaskCompletionSource` that does accept a `CancellationToken` and cancels itself when the `TaskCompletionSource` is cancelled:

```
class TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation<T> : TaskCompletionSource<T>
{
    public CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; }

    public TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        var cancellationTokenRegistration =
            cancellationToken.Register(
                _ => ((TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation<TResult>)_).TrySetCanceled(),
                this);
        Task.ContinueWith(_ => cancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose());
    }
}
```

Comment: is it considered good practice to rely on canceling a TaskCompletionSource? I am trying to build a pubsub, and I was using TaskCompletionSource to get a subscription.

Comment: Only asking this question because TaskCompletionSource was not designed specifically to hold a CancellationToken.

Comment: @Arthis I can't see why you would need a TCS and TPL Dataflow both. If you only need something to asynchronously wait on TCS is enough.

Comment: I tried to explain on this programmers question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/309798/pubsub-using-actionblock